# Implementing iterator to an ArrayList

Tags: java, iterator

I am having trouble with my code to add iterator support to ArrayList
this is the class i create to implement Iterator

```
class MyArrayListIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {
private E[] list = null;
private int currentIndex = 0;

@Override
public boolean hasNext() {
    if (currentIndex < list.length) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public E next(){
    return list[currentIndex++];
}
```

}
This must include, which i think i did correct

"list" of type MyArrayList
"currentIndex" of type int, initially at zero

This is my main method for testing

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    MyList<String> names = new MyArrayList<>();
    
    names.add("Steve");
    names.add("Frank");
    names.add("Heather");
    names.add("Chris");
    names.add("Oliver");
    
      for (String string : names) {   // error at names Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable
            System.out.println(string);
        }
}
```

}

In the myArrayList i have added as the requirement is Make MyArrayList implement the Iterable interface by adding the iterator() method, which should return an instance of MyArrayListIterator.

```
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return new MyArrayListIterator();
}
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Where's your `next()` implementation?

Comment: Does MyList extend Iterable?

Comment: I have added next() and it did not extend Iterable

Comment: You never seem to initialize `list` to a non-`null` value, so I assume you're getting a `NullPointerException`. If that's not the case then please clarify how your code is not working.

Comment: extending Iterable removed all errors but once i ran the code I received Cannot read the array length because "this.list" is null

Comment: Yes, that's a `NullPointerException`. This likely makes your question a duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

Comment: how do i fix this?  i read the link provided but it's still not clear

Comment: Create a parameter to the constructor for `MyArrayListIterator` and use that to initialize the `list` field.

Comment: You're trying to iterate something, presumably the array in your `MyArrayList` class. Inside the `MyArrayListIterator` you never initialize `list` to anything. So I would assume the fix is to initialize `list` to the same instance as, or a copy of, the "list" in the outer class.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments, your problem is that you read from `list` in `MyArrayListIterator` without initializing it. This causes a `NullPointerException`.

You can fix this in two different ways:

1. Make `MyArrayListIterator` a `non-static nested` (they are also called `inner classes`) class of `MyArrayList`.

   By doing so, you get access to all fields of the outer-class, which in this case is `MyArrayList`. For example, see this code snippet:

```java
public class MyArrayList<E> implements MyList<E> {
  private Object[] list = new Object[10];
  private int size = 0;

  public Iterator<E> iterator(){
    return new MyArrayListIterator<>();
  }

  // more of your implementation...

  // This is the inner class
  private class MyArrayListIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
    private int currentIndex = 0;

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
      // Since this is a inner class, we have access to the
      // "list" field defined by MyArrayList.
      return currentIndex < list.length;
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
      // Since this is a inner class, we have access to the
      // "list" field defined by MyArrayList.
      return (T) list[currentIndex++];
    }
  }
}
```

2. Make `MyArrayListIterator` a `static nested` class or a separate class.

   In this case, you don't have access to the fields defined in `MyArrayList`, which means you have to provide them yourself. This can be done using the constructor.

```java
public class MyArrayList<E> implements MyList<E> {
  private Object[] list = new Object[10];
  private int size = 0;

  public Iterator<E> iterator(){
    return new MyArrayListIterator<>((E[])list);
  }

  // More of your list implementation

  // This is a static inner class, which means we do not have access to
  // the fields of the outer class.
  private static class MyArrayListIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
    private final T[] elements;
    private int currentIndex = 0;

    public MyArrayListIterator(T[] elements) {
      this.elements = elements;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
      // Since we got the elements as constructor argument, they are not
      // null (assuming you did not call it with null as parameter).
      return currentIndex < elements.length;
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
      // Since we got the elements as constructor argument, they are not
      // null (assuming you did not call it with null as parameter).
      return elements[currentIndex++];
    }
  }
}
```

For more information on nested classes, see [this tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) on nested classes.